# MVC Razor Actionlink issue with routevalue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying an actionlink with the following code :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product",
    new {
        @class = horizontal ? "btn btn-default btn-sm" :
            "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
    })
```

However this gives me an error unless I add null for the routevalues before the html attributes. I can't figure out why this is so. Could this be a mvc version issue  or perhaps I'm referencing the wrong dll somewhere ?

Please assist. I was following the Sportsstore example application by Adam Freeman(Apress) and his code doesn't have the null for routevalues and apparently works.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the wrong overload - see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Not a version issue - there has never been an overload that accepted just `linkText`, `actionName`, `controllerName`, `routeValues` (your either not following the example correctly, or the example is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few overloads for [ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). The one you need is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

You are trying to pass an anonymous `object` of htmlAttributes. To match the signature your `routeValues` needs to contain a value (null in this case). There is no overload with three strings and one object as a parameter, therefore you get an error.

Comment: OP is including the controller name so the its [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) that's needed.